# DOS Attack on incomplete requests ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ddos

I have an application that gets DOSed if it received incomplete/slow http requests. I debugged and found the reason to be that when I try to access the HTTP Request, the application stalls until the request is complete. I need a way to tell me in the Request is complete or not. something like `Request.IsComplete()`

EDIT

Example:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
         Log(Request["Query"]);
    }
```

The request tries to get Request[Query] forever.

I created a client that can be abstracted as below

```
        socket.Connect(uri.Host, uri.Port);
        SendRequest(socket, uri, payload, bytesToTruncate);
        socket.Close();
```

If I go in debug mode, after `SendRequest()`, The request goes into `Application_BeginRequest()` before `socket.Close()` is called, but I will not be able to access `Request["Query"]` in `Application_BeginRequest` until `socket.Close()` is called. It basically stops and waits for the `socket.Close/Request` to be complete

Comment: Please show how you "access the HTTP request". I don't think http.sys forwards requests before they're complete. Edit: nevermind, it does that.

Comment: Give us a minimal complete verifiable example that reproduces this issue (you can even do it by showing us an action that sets a timer and doesn't return until that timer is done); so that we can be sure your code isn't the issue.

Comment: Can you post the code responsible for the stall?

Comment: Edited with more insights of what's happening. I hope you understand the problem now

Comment: What does `Log` refer to?

Comment: Any operation that's happening, it's actually irrelevant here since the code never gets past Request["Query"]